# Dropbox doesn't connect properly on boot

Tags: networking, arch-linux, networkmanager, dropbox

I'm having a problem with Dropbox (version 1.1.35). When I first boot it takes some time before Network Manager connects to the WLAN. Then I see the Dropbox icon in the task list, claiming to be "Connecting...", but never finishing. If I exit and start it again, everything works fine. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved with help of [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dropbox).

/opt/dropbox/dropboxd was replaced with:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copyright 2008 Evenflow, Inc., 2010 Dropbox
#
# Environment script for the dropbox executable.

start_dropbox() {
PAR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PAR:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 

TMP1=`ps ax|grep dropbox|grep -v grep`
if [ -n "$TMP1" ]; then
  kill -9 $(pidof dropbox) >/dev/null 2>&1
fi
exec $PAR/dropbox $@ &
}

do_dropbox() {
start_dropbox >/dev/null 2>&1
while [ 1 ]; do
  sleep 5
  ERROR="$(net_test)"
  if [ -n "$ERROR" ]; then
    LAST_ERROR=1
  else
    if [ -n "$LAST_ERROR" ]; then
      # Connection seems to be up but last cycle was down
      LAST_ERROR=""
      start_dropbox >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
  fi
done

}

net_test() {
TMP1="$(ifconfig |grep "inet addr:" |grep -v "127.0.0.1")"
[ -z "$TMP1" ] && echo "error"
}

do_dropbox
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sleep` to delay the start of dropbox until after your network connection is up. Put something like this in your `.xinitrc` or your `autostart`, depending on your DE or WM:

`(sleep 30 && $HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd) &`

Comment: Unfortunately did not work for me :( I have add it to my .xinitrc file, but dropbox did not start at all. Are there any other ideas

Comment: It has worked for me for some time now: if you issue the same command from a terminal does it start?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Problem solved, see below. Your solution was working from the command line, but not from .xinitrc

Comment: @jasonwryan: This works for me from a terminal but not from within .xinitrc. Any ideas?

Comment: @Rahul I'm not sure why it wouldn't work from `.xinitrc` - I have used this method on Arch for a couple of years now with no problems...

Comment: @jasonwryan: Beats me. Anyway, I got it working using nautilus-dropbox and enabling "Start Dropbox on system startup" in the General tab of the Preferences accessed via the Dropbox tray icon.